# How do I conditionally add a filter to ng-repeat inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I am using an element directive on several views. The directive repeats for each 'resource' in a list of resources, simply like this: `ng-repeat="resource in resources"`.

Different page controllers will determine which resources will get pulled from the API by having a different `$scope.resourceApiPath` in each view controller that the directive controller then uses to make an `$http` call.

This works well for different views that display different resources. For example one view displays all the user's own resources, one view displays public resources, one view displays resources the user has starred, etc.

The only problem is that for one of my views I want to add a filter on the `ng-repeat` like so: `ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:resourceSearch.text"`. is there a way for me to add this filter depending on a condition, e.g. if `$scope.filter == true;`, otherwise simply returning the regular `ng-repeat="resource in resources"`?

This is my directive:

```
.directive('resourcePanel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'scripts/templates/resource-panel.html',
        controller: 'ResourcesPanelController'
    }
})
```

The `ResourcesPanelController` referenced in the directive has something like this:

```
$scope.resources = [];
$scope.loadResources = function() {
    $scope.resources = []; // Empty the array
    $http.get('/api/resource' + $scope.resourceApiPath)
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.resources = res.data.message;
        });
};
$scope.loadResources();
```

The `scripts/templates/resource-panel.html` element template looks something like this:

```
<div class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources">
    {{resource.content}}
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can do one of four ways , i prefer 1 and 3 but its totally depend on your requirement and code standard which one suits best for you.

Custom filter is also a clean solution.

1. If you are using text value for filter then, if you don't set the value of resourceSearch.text then its as good as no filter, so if resourceSearch.text exist it will filter and if its undefined then no filter.

   ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:resourceSearch.text"
2. Create a custom filter and handle it there.

if you want to create a custom filter then use enable argument which you can use to on and off your filter http://plnkr.co/edit/ilPJPUZkBC7Y5OvGHWey?p=preview i have found a plunkr as well for custom filter which suits your need

```
ng-repeat="resource in resources | customfilter:resourceSearch.text:enable"
```

3. Filter your final resources in controller and pass filtered value to html
4. use ng-if with your condition if filter exist then one loop and if its not there then different loop.

i hope it will help.

Comment: I decided to use your `enable` argument, as this was the simplest way of integrating it with my current setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom filter function:

```
$scope.conditionalFilter = function(resource) {
    if (!$scope.filter) {
        return true;
    }

    // normal filter logic goes here, e.g.
    return resource.content.indexOf($scope.resourceSearch.text) >= 0;
};
```

Then in your template just use the custom filter:

```
<div class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:conditionalFilter">
    {{resource.content}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="!filter" class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources">
    {{resource.content}}
</div>
<div ng-if="filter" class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources| filter:resourceSearch.text">
    {{resource.content}}
</div>
```

Sorry for the no description, I use this sometimes if im pretty sure it only shows up once, since when you flatten it..

```
<div ng-if="!filter" class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources">{{resource.content}}</div>
<div ng-if="filter" class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources|filter:resourceSearch.text">{{resource.content}}</div>
```

then it really doesn't look that bad.

But a more complete solution would be setting up a a custom filter and injecting 'filter'

```
app.filter('conditionalFilter', function (filter) {
  return function (item, condition) {
    if(condition){
       return filter.bind(this,item).apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments,2));
    } else{ return item }
  };
});
```

and then

```
<div class="panel" ng-repeat="resource in resources| conditionalfilter : !!filter : researchSearch.text" >
    {{resource.content}}
</div>
```

Haven't tested, let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: Problem with this is that I've actually massively simplified the template: there is actually a ton more code that goes into the panel, so this would entail writing it all out twice, which is very WET - not to mention goes against the reason for separating it out into a template in the first place.

Comment: @Aron WET being the opposite of DRY? That's a new one :)

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. While the OP may know what you mean, not everyone who sees this question and answer will, and Stack Overflow is a repository of knowledge, not a place for one person to get the help that helps them and nothing else

Comment: @shmosel, yep, it stands for Write Everything Twice :)